# Wordpress shows 404 on pages 11 and above?

Tags: 404-error

Recently I noticed that every page on post list above 10 shows 404 error. My site is http://skuvajme.com/, hosted on site5 and I'm using modified "Magazine Basic" theme.

http://skuvajme.com/page/10 is visible.
http://skuvajme.com/page/11 returns 404 error.

I don't have much experience with wordpress and php. Can someone help me to to fix this error?

Comment: "Can someone help me to to fix this error?" -- No, not likely without [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and probably some code.

Comment: This is typical of overriding pagination in template file (typically with `query_posts()` call). There aren't enough details here to make better guess. You should probably start with asking theme's developer.